# Build a validation parameter decorator in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I read the doc, been there, done that. Still no clue how to write a decorator I need in a way that makes common sense.

**In brief**: Got an interceptor that executes before the validation layer. That simply means that invalid data can get in the interceptor and break the app. To avoid that I would like to use a decorator on some methods, and to be more accurate on parameters of such methods.

```
public async getUserById(@IsIntNumber() userId: number): Promise<UserEntity>
{
    // method logic
}
```

Here `@IsIntNumber()` is a custom decorator that validates the `userId` parameter.

As a matter of fact I'd like to have a little library of mine in the application holding a bunch a that kinds of validation decorators that I could apply to different parameters.

Is there some legal method to do this without shedding too much blood and too many tears?

I know it's a difficult question.

In the docs they sort of say:

> The @required decorator adds a metadata entry that marks the parameter
> as required. The @validate decorator then wraps the existing greet
> method in a function that validates the arguments before invoking the
> original method.

Meaning I've got to pack all my validation logic into that `validate` function or what? Really?

Does it mean that we don't have adequate parameter decorators in TS? Cos if I understand this right, these ones are absolutely, totally unusable.